# AS3 Is this code creating a MC Variable?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created some MC dynamicallly and did what I thought would be assigning values to variables in the MC's as I generated them e.g.

```
        my_mc.name = "mc" + i + j;
        trace("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^****************" + my_mc.name); // Works

        my_mc.mcRow = j + 1; // Thinking I'm assigning values to a variable
        trace("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^****************" + my_mc.mcRow); // Works

        addChild(my_mc);
```

So, the trace outputs do what I expect, however, when I try to use/output the mcRow values later, they do not show up e.g.

```
    var my_FC_row = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r).name; // Works
    var cxmy_FC_row = [my_FC_row].mcRow; // No value- does not work
    var my_FC_name = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r).name; // Works
    var my_FC_x = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r).x; // Works
    var my_FC_y = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r).y; // Works
    cellData[r] = [my_FC_name, my_FC_x, my_FC_y, cxmy_FC_row];
    trace("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ :" + r +" : "+ cellData[r]);
```

This code is in another function but I thought that the MC would still hold the value for mcRow.

What have I done/assumed incorrectly?

Comment: Just before you `addChild(my_mc);` can you do `trace(this, this.name, root, root.name);` Just to make sure what you are adding too actually is the root?

Comment: If I do that, I get [object MainTimeline] root1 [object MainTimeline] root1 - which means it's definitely the root?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 var my_FC_row = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r); // Works
 var cxmy_FC_row = my_FC_row.mcRow; // Works
```

Comment: I get an error when I try that: Error #1069: Property mcRow not found on String and there is no default value

Comment: remove the ".name" from the first line, ie var my_FC_row = (root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(r); Kindly do the the changes in first 2 lines as above

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I tried the code and it produced the error above. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I dropped the .name and that worked! Thanks. Why did that work?

Comment: my_FC_row , in ur sample , takes the name , ie string of the movieclip. It will never have the attribute mcRow into it. if you remove the ".name" , what u'll get is movieclip object. so that object.mcRow will always return the proper value

Comment: Many thanks. A fundamental misunderstanding which will help in future!

Comment: Oh bugger, I completely missed that in the original example. Good catch.